# jquery wysiwyg post layout issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wysiwyg

I am facing a problem with the jquery wysiwyg. The problem occurs when the new edited text is being updated and saved in the database. The problem is that the text that I save is being posted without the layout(for example without bold or new line) to the database. All the text is just pasted and stuck one after the other. The database field is set to TEXT.

Example:

**This is a bold text**

This is a new line

Becomes after saving: This is a bold textThis is a new line

Can anyone help me out?

code in php

```
$mails = $db->search('mail');
$tpl->assign('mails', $mails); 

if ($_POST['save']) {
foreach($mails as $mail) {
    $db->id = $mail['MailID'];
    $db->text = $_POST['text'.$mail['MailID']];
    $db->save('mail');
}
header('Refresh: 0');
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpqxP.jpg see image for issue

---

Code single page

```
{literal}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var editors = $('#form textarea');
            $.each(editors, function () {
                $(this).wysiwyg();
            });
        });
    </script>
{/literal}

        <!-- START CONTENT -->
        <div class="content">
            <form method="post" action="" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-    data">

                <!-- START jWYSIWYG TEXT EDITOR -->
                {foreach from=$mails item=mail}
                    <div class="simplebox grid740">
                        <div class="titleh">
                            <h3>{$mail.title}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="body">
                            <textarea class="st-forminput"         name="text{$mail.MailID}" rows="5" cols="47" style="width:96.5%;">{$mail.text}    </textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {/foreach}
                <!-- END jWYSIWYG TEXT EDITOR -->

                <div class="button-box center">
                    <input type="submit" name="save" id="button" value="Save"             class="st-button"/>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: show some of your code

Comment: "the" jquery wysiwyg? there is an official wysiwyg for jquery???

Comment: Use the debugger to see what is being sent to the server.

Comment: @depperm showed the code

Comment: @AndrewR I already tried debugging but still can't find what the issue is

Comment: Double check the database to see what is being saved. If it looks correct, then your issue is with the load. If it's missing the html tags, then it's a problem with the save.

Comment: Okey I checked and The database does not contain any html tags, can anyone consult how I correctly can save with html tags?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should ensure that what you are posting, actually contains the html tags. If it is then try this for saving https://stackoverflow.com/a/4577962/1084306. I believe you need to ensure you are encoding the data before you insert. And vice versa, you will need to decode it to render on the page.

Comment: Did you already do this? "ensure that what you are posting, actually contains the html tags". What does the data look like from the database?

Comment: Yes I tried to activate the html on the jWYSIWYG to make sure that the text that is posted to the database is in html format, but somehow it still does not posts it correctly

Comment: Tina what is the value of `$_POST['text'.$mail['MailID']];` before you insert into the database?

Comment: Ok sounds like the issue is the wysiwig not posting html data. Which Wysiwig are you using? Can you provide some code/link to code? (for the WYSIWIG that is)

Comment: Ok. How are you passing that value on to the next page? Jquery or just a form submit? And when you do `var_dump($_POST['text'.$mail['MailID']])` on the save page, what value do you get?

Comment: I am using multiple textareas that are executed by an for loop. and when I am saving the content I use a button that posts a form, and with the code above putting into the database. All is done by using one single page(so posting/saving and returning to the same page). var_dump returns NULL butt it is saving the content

Comment: Have you tried to validate before saving the page? Validate that the wysiwig editor actually contains the value expected? `$("#original").wysiwyg("getContent");` I would also maybe just include one text area in the form and get that working before including all that show in the loop.

Comment: Here is another link you may or may not have checked out, although it's related to the iframe version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865629/jquery-jquery-wysiwyg-return-html-as-a-string